# Spark job taking longer time if core reduce to half

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am using spark 1.6.0 for my project and running in single cluster mode, Previously my system has 8 core and it is able to process all records within 2 min but when i am using only 4 cores and rest of the configuration is same it takes more than 3 hour to complete the job. I am confuse on reducing core by half why my job taking this much time.

Comment: What is your configs?

Comment: Can you provide the spark submit config?

Comment: spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/config/log4j.properties" --class com.reduce.calculate /home/deployment/target/calculates-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/config/sparkrel.properties  and in properties file  core setting:- master=local[*] @diogoramos

Comment: Please provide the content of /home/config/sparkrel.properties